# Angular styleguide. Использование контроллеров в шаблоне

Tags: javascript, angularjs, code-style

В [стайл-гайде](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide) по Ангуляру от Тода Мотто есть такая рекомендация:

```
<!-- avoid -->
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{ someObject }}
  </div>

<!-- recommended -->
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    {{ vm.someObject }}
  </div>
```

Чем лучше рекомендованный вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в Angular, если переменная в текущем scope не найдена, то она ищется в scope родителя, и так вплоть до рута (`$rootScope`). Используя алиасы для контроллеров мы инкапсулируем его scope.

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('ParentCtrl', ParentCtrl)
    .controller('ChildCtrl', ChildCtrl);

ParentCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ParentCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.someObject = 'parent';
}

ChildCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">  
        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
            {{ someObject }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В примере мы наглядно видем, что обращась к переменной `someObject` из скоупа контроллера `ChildCtr` мы получили переменную, которую задали в контроллере `ParentCtrl`.

Ещё один пример, который демонстрирует обращение к родительской переменной при одинаковых именах переменной в том и другом скоупе.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('ParentCtrl', ParentCtrl)
    .controller('ChildCtrl', ChildCtrl);

ParentCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ParentCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.someObject = 'parent';
}

ChildCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.someObject = 'child';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">  
        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
            {{ someObject }} {{ $parent.someObject }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пример с алиасами:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('ParentCtrl', ParentCtrl)
    .controller('ChildCtrl', ChildCtrl);

function ParentCtrl() {    
    this.someObject = 'parent';
}

function ChildCtrl() {
    this.someObject = 'child';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl  as parent">  
        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as child">
            {{ child.someObject }}
          
            {{ parent.someObject }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вы могли заметить, что запись при таком варианте представления отличается. Иcпользуется `this`.

Рекомендация: Чтобы наглядно видеть всё дерево scopes существует официальная утилита для браузера chrome от команды разработчиков Angular: [AngularJS Batarang](https://github.com/angular/batarang).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, хотя преимуществ этой рекомендации так и не увидел)

Батараг да, использую, только во многих местах при его запуске он ругается на превышение итераций digest, выдавая ошибку в консоль  и я не понимаю почем.

Comment: @Harvey: `хотя преимуществ этой рекомендации так и не увидел` Вы правы, конфликты (неожиданные поведения) могут возникнуть в достаточно крупных проектах, с множеством scopes.